# Problem with maximun reactions Discord.js

Tags: node.js, discord.js

my goal is to use a command that add reactions and you can react to change the text, so when I click and the reaction 1 that's edit the original text to : 1 and same for the others... that's pretty much working, but when i'm trying to remove and re-add the reaction, that's not working I think it's because of : `{ max: 1 }` here's my code :

```
bot.on('message', msg => {
    if(msg.content === PREFIX + "test") {
        msg.channel.send(`${msg.author.username}, exemple`).then((sentMessage) => {
            
            setTimeout(function() {
                sentMessage.react("⏪");
            }, 500);

            setTimeout(function() {
                sentMessage.react("⬅️");
            }, 1000);

            setTimeout(function() {
                sentMessage.react("➡️");
            }, 1500);

            setTimeout(function() {
                sentMessage.react("⏩");
            }, 2000);

            let reactionFilter = (reaction, user) => {
                reaction.emoji.name === '⏪' && user.id !== "bot id" && user.id == msg.author.id
            }
            sentMessage.awaitReactions(reactionFilter, { max: 1 }).then(() => {
                sentMessage.edit(`1`)
                }
            )

            let reactionFilter2 = (reaction, user) => { 
                reaction.emoji.name === '⬅️' && user.id !== "bot id" && user.id === msg.author.id
            }
            sentMessage.awaitReactions(reactionFilter2, { max: 1 }).then(() => {
                sentMessage.edit(`2`)
                }
            )

            let reactionFilter3 = (reaction, user) => {
                reaction.emoji.name === '➡️' && user.id !== "bot id" && user.id === msg.author.id
            }
            sentMessage.awaitReactions(reactionFilter3, { max: 1 }).then(() => {
                sentMessage.edit(`3`)
                }
            )

            let reactionFilter4 = (reaction, user) => {
                reaction.emoji.name === '⏩' && user.id !== "bot id" && user.id === msg.author.id
            }
            sentMessage.awaitReactions(reactionFilter4, { max: 1 }).then(() => {
                sentMessage.edit(`4`)
                }
            )
        })
    }
})
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it's because of the max limit, you should prob instead be using one reaction collector instead:

```js
const emojis = ["⏪", "⬅️", "➡️", "⏩"];
//no need to check if the user id isnt the bot 
const filter = (reaction, user) => emojis.includes(reaction.emoji.name) && user.id === msg.author.id;

// adding a time is probably a better option
const collector = sentMessage.createReactionCollector(filter, { time: 5000 });
collector.on("collect", reaction => {
    // array is 0 indexed so just add 1 to the index and you get the number you wanted
    // might need to convert the number into a string aswell
    sentMessage.edit("" + (emojis.indexOf(reaction.emoji.name) + 1));
});
```

Should note this doesn't do anything if a reaction is removed, which I think is best because it would be hard to decide what the text should be after it's removed